# How to tell gradle not to compress dependency Java project resources or tell it that dependency Java project resources are assets?

Tags: android, build, gradle, assets

I have a sub-project that contains only project resources, especially sounds:

```
assets/
  src/
    main/
      resources/
        assets/
          sound.mp3
          ...
  build.gradle
```

Its build.gradle is only:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

Another sub-project is Android application which depends on the assets sub-project:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
  compile project(':assets')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

Application compiles fine and files are merged to assets folder in the resulting APK but when I try to play that sound, I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed
```

because the depencency project resources are compressed.

Explicitly disabling compression for mp3 files does not work, since it is probably applied only on android sub-project assets:

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress 'mp3', 'wav', 'ogg', 'png'
}
```

When I include the file in android project assets it plays fine but then I cannot share this file accross multiple projects.

I can't make the assets project "android-library" because some regular Java projects depends on it. (Or can I have one physic directory containing two build.gradle files and include each of them in different sub-projects as different dependencies?)

So this brings me a title question:

**How to tell gradle not to compress dependency Java project resources or tell it that dependency Java project resources are assets?**

Comment: I've used Gradle a lot and would like to help, but I don't understand what you're asking. Can you take a bit more time, reduce the problem to its essence and explain it more clearly? I'm not sure if your question is about Gradle configuration (as implied by the title) or Android plugin configuration (as implied by the text).

Comment: Sorry that I hadn't make myself clear. The problem is that in the final APK the assets coming from Java sup-project dependency are compressed and Android platform cannot play compressed sounds. I believe that if I'd include android-library project with sounds as the Android project dependency, the sounds would be working. I cannot do that because the assets project is shared with Java (and other) projects that don't know how to work with android-library projects.

Comment: It seem like the APK is compiled from Android project and processed using normal tools respecting configuration that certain assets files should not be compressed and then the dependency project is packaged into the APK compressed.

Comment: So I'm pretty sure that I understand what is wrong but I don't know Gradle and Gradle Android plugin build process deep enough to identify what could be changed so that dependency project resource files are attached to the assets directory uncompressed.

Comment: Have you tried using the `raw` directory instead of `assets`?

Comment: How? How do you include depencency Java project resources into APK raw resources?